# Loop in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, pdftk

I must rename more hundred files, they are numbered

on the left, from 01 to 100, on the right side from G3002185 to G3002285

i use this script

```
rename  01.pdf G3002185.pdf
rename  02.pdf G3002186.pdf
rename  03.pdf G3002187.pdf
rename  04.pdf G3002188.pdf
rename  05.pdf G3002189.pdf
rename  06.pdf G3002130.pdf
(...)
```

but I would like to shorten it, is there an option to loop it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /L %%c IN (1001,1,1100) DO (
 SET "oldname=%%c"
 SET /a newname=3002185 - 1001 + %%c
 IF %%c==1100 (SET "oldname=!oldname:~-3!") ELSE (SET "oldname=!oldname:~-2!")
 ECHO REN "!oldname!.pdf" "G!newname!.pdf"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Your example appears to be faulty. "06" should be renamed to "G3002190".

And your count is incorrect. The last new-filename should be "G3002284.pdf"